# Populate UITableView from private core data child context

Tags: ios, core-data

This is a follow up question to this one: [Core Data concurrency with NSPersistentContainer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176830/core-data-concurrency-with-nspersistentcontainer)

I am creating `NSManagedObjects` in a child context (using `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`) that I would like to display in a `UITableView` backed by an `NSFetchedResultsController` before saving them to the store.

Creating the objects works, and I am fetching them from the child context. But I get a crash when I am populating the cells using the info in the managed objects.

I am guessing because the objects were created on a different thread?

I don't want to save the objects until the user taps the Save button. In the question above I came up with a workaround, but it feels like a hack.

So how could I fix this? is it even possible to update the UI with objects from a private child context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the child context a mainQueue concurrency type.  Since you need to display the data in the UI it must be on the main thread.

Comment: Gotcha. Or maybe even use a third private context where I generate everything on another thread, then copy it to the mainQueue child context to display it? And then to the store when the user hits 'save'.