# NSMergeConflict with oldVersion and newVersion reported as being equal

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I recently managed to catch an extremely rare exception in my code and was hoping folks here could help me understand it.  I have a game which is tracking elapsed time and persisting the value to Core Data every second.  At the same time a user could be playing the game and causing the score to update, which is also saved in Core Data.  I suspect that I should be serializing saves, but at the moment I'm not.  Everything works great 99.99% of the time, but once in a while the call to `context.save()` throws an exception.

I have a merge policy set as so:

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
```

And here's how I save elapsed time.  The same pattern is used for updating a player's score.

```
func saveElapsedTime() {
    let container = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer
    container.performBackgroundTask() { (context) in
        let storedGame = context.object(with: self.storedGameID) as! StoredGame
        storedGame.elapsedTime = Int32(self.elapsedTime)

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let nserror as NSError {
            print("saveElapsedTime: failed to save: \(nserror). userInfo: \(nserror.userInfo).")
        }
    }
}
```

The rare error I was able to catch looks like this:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=133020 "Could not resolve merge changes."
<snip>...with oldVersion = 463 and newVersion = 463...<snip>
```

I've seen plenty of posts where the old and new versions are off by one or a small number, and people recommend setting a merge policy which is different than the default. I'm guessing that in my case where oldVersion == newVersion it's because multiple threads are trying to save at the exact same time.  Can someone confirm this just by looking at the error message?  Should I be serializing all saves using an OperationQueue like in this example: [NSPersistentContainer concurrency for saving to core data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733574/nspersistentcontainer-concurrency-for-saving-to-core-data/42745378#42745378)?

Thanks in advance.